# Should Java enums be defined in their own files?

Tags: java, coding-style, enums

If I've understood enums correctly, a good example would be to use them to store the suite of a playing card instead of four magic numbers or four static final ints.

```
public class Card {
    // ...
    private enum CARD_SUITE { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES; }
}
```

But what if a public method of `Card` needs a suite as argument, e.g. `isSuite(CARD_SUITE suite)`? The enumeration is private to the class. Making a new file for that single line feels very unnecessary. How is this solved?

Comment: You can make it public in the same file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make it `public` in the same class, only public `class` should be defined in a separate Java file.

```
public class Card {
    // ...
    public enum CARD_SUITE { HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS, SPADES; }
}
```

You can then access the `enum` like `Card.CARD_SUITE.HEARTS`, `Card.CARD_SUITE.DIAMONDS`...

Comment: Wow, I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sure,

just put it in separate file.

And try in the future to use separate file per`enum` for good code maintenance.

But if you going to use `enum` only for one class, set it `private`

**ECardSuite.java**

```
public enum ECardSuite {
 HEARTS,
 DIAMONDS,
 CLUBS,
 SPADES; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a public CARD_SUITE enum in your Card class. It makes sense if the enum is just a list of values.

If your enum has some methods, implements some interfaces, etc. it is better to define it in its own file.

Answer (score 1):

I personally make enums like that public. The enum belongs to that class (hence no separate file for it) and it is safe to make it public (you can't change it anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Enums are normal Java classes, so it is completely proper to make a separate class file for them.

In my opinion it's definitely clearer and easier to search.